# How to auto assign ordinal ranking in mysql with as minimal queries for new rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+
| id | view_id | user_id | ordinal_ranking |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+
|  1 |      10 |       1 |               1 |
|  2 |      10 |       2 |               1 |
|  3 |      11 |       1 |               2 |
|  4 |      11 |       2 |               2 |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

So suppose I want to insert new rows for view_id 12 and for both user_id 1 and 2, these 2 new rows should have ordinal ranking of 3.

**How do I do that with minimal number of queries?**

Bear in mind, I have many users who may all have different number of views assigned.

Another corollary to the problem is when I need to delete a particular view, say view 10, all the users affected should have the ordinal ranking re-ordered.

**How do I do that also with minimal number of queries?**

**EDIT**

A comment was made about the number of views per user. I would like to add that you may safely assume that there is a `users` table and one column stores the number of views for each user record.

I am also okay if the ordinal ranking is zero-based, ie the ranking is 0, 1, 2, 3, etc

I also prefer not to use stored procedures.

**EDIT2**:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | name | view_count |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |     Sal |       2 |
|  2 |     Sam |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Is the `users` table

the `ordinal_ranking` merely reflects the personal choice of a user with regards to the views she can view.

E.g. user 1 Sal likes to have view 10 to be ranked higher than view 11.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are the number of views per view_id ? You are showing the `ordinal_ranking` but you have not told us what table/column has the number of views.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA is the number of views per user important? if so, you can assume that the users table has a field that stores the number of views for each user record

Comment: Please include the table design of the `user` table.

Comment: Please also explain what is being ranked. Having id 1 and 2 with ordinal_ranking=1 and id 3 and 4 with ordinal_ranking=2 does not tell us what the views counts are, or whether the ranking is based on the user, the views, or a combination of both.

Comment: Question updated to add in users table and to indicate what the ordinal ranking represents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table is called `users_access_views` and the primary key `id` is auto increment and assuming there is a `users` table,

**Scenario 1a) Insert new view and have it be the last view of all the users who has at least access to 1 view**

To insert a new view_id regardless of how many views each user already is assigned to and this new view_id is 3 and ensure the ordinal ranking is obeyed,

```
INSERT INTO users_access_views (view_id, user_id, ordinal_ranking) 
SELECT 3, user_id, count(id) + 1 from users_access_views group by user_id;
```

**Scenario 1b) Insert new view and have it be the last view of all the selected users regardless if they already have any views**

If on the other hand, you want to add selected users and there is a chance some of these users do not already have any access to any views, let us assume that the users involved are user 1, 2, 3

```
INSERT INTO users_access_views (view_id, user_id, ordinal_ranking) 
SELECT 3, u.id, count(uav.id) + 1 from users_access_views uav
  RIGHT JOIN users u ON uav.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.id in (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

**Scenario 2) Delete existing view and reorder the ordinal_ranking after the deletion**

To delete an existing view_id regardless of how many each user already is assigned to and this removed view_id is 2 and ensure the ordinal ranking is obeyed,

```
-- delete all the view_id 2 first

DELETE FROM users_access_views where view_id = 2;

-- update the ordinal ranking 

UPDATE users_access_views ua4 INNER JOIN

-- this subquery temp table inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/25763224/80353    
(SELECT ua1.id, ua1.user_id, ua1.view_id, count(ua2.id) + 1 as rank
FROM  users_access_views ua1 LEFT JOIN users_access_views ua2 ON 
ua1.ordinal_ranking>ua2.ordinal_ranking and ua1.user_id = ua2.user_id 
GROUP BY  ua1.id, ua1.user_id, ua1.view_id) ua3 

ON ua3.id = ua4.id 
SET
  ua4.ordinal_ranking = ua3.rank;
```

If need be, have another query that updates the `view_count` in the `users` table after each scenario.

Comment: Very sweet solution, especially the delete query. +1 !!!

Comment: Your are welcome, and thank you for the bounty !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are content with adding and deleting a view_id per user_id, here is what I see

## Adding View 12 To User 10

I see three queries

- Insert new view into user with BogusRank
- Move all rank down below NewRank
- Change BogusRank to New Rank for new view

Here is the proposed code

```
SET @view_id = 12;
SET @user_id = 10;
SET @newrank = 3;
SET @defrank = 999999999;
INSERT INTO userviewranks
(view_id,user_id,ordinal_ranking)
VALUES (@view_id,@user_id,@defrank);
UPDATE userviewranks SET ordinal_ranking = ordinal_ranking + 1
WHERE view_id = @view_id AND user_id = @user_id AND ordinal_ranking >= @newrank;
UPDATE userviewranks SET ordinal_ranking = @newrank
WHERE view_id = @view_id AND user_id = @user_id AND ordinal_ranking = @defrank;
```

## Deleting View 12 From User 10

I see three queries

- Retrieve Row With View to Delete
- Move All View Up in Rank
- Delete Row with Old View

Here is the proposed code

```
SET @view_id = 12;
SET @user_id = 10;
SELECT id,ordinal_ranking INTO @id_to_zap,@rank_to_zap FROM userviewranks
WHERE view_id = @view_id AND user_id = @user_id;
UPDATE userviewranks SET ordinal_ranking = ordinal_ranking - 1
WHERE view_id = @view_id AND user_id = @user_id AND ordinal_ranking > @rank_to_zap;
DELETE FROM userviewranks WHERE id = @id_to_zap;
```

Comment: My question states "When I want to insert new rows for view_id 12 and for both user_id 1 and 2", the new rows for view_id 12 and for both users should be 3. In other words, not just update for 1 user, but multiple users. and bear in mind, it is entirely possible that some users have more views hence when adding view_id 12 it may not be 3 for certain users.

Comment: I solved it. I will award you the 50 points anyway. Thank you Rolando